# On/ Off button action control Using Flask and HTML

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am beginner in web development. I have an button Using HTML and CSS. Like this,

```css
.button_1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20 px;
  top: 95px;
  left: 45px;
}

.button_1 input {
  display: none;
}

.button_1_span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.button_1_span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: -36px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.button_1 input:checked+.button_1_span {
  background: green;
}

.button_1 input:checked+.button_1_span:before {
  left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<label class="button_1">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="button_1_span"></span>
</label>
```

In this button there is two position red and green. Now, I want `to call two python function using flask depends on red and green position of my button`. Sample flask code is given here,

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('button.html')

@app.route('/at_red_position_button/')
def my_detection():
  print ('From  red_position_button')

  return 'Red.'
  

@app.route('/at_green_position_button/')
def my_reading():
  print ('From  Green_position_button')

  return 'Green.'
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

**As, I am beginner I will appreciate any kinds of help. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=call+flask+on+click+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO;

Comment: jQuery: `$(".button_1 input").on("click",function() { $.get(this.checked? "/at_green_position_button/" :  "/at_red_position_button/", function(data) { console.log(data)})`

Comment: @mplungjan I am not familiar with jQuery. Could you please add an answer how to do that, it would be helpful for me ? Anyway, Thanks for you help.

Comment: 1. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` to the head of the html page

Comment: 2. Add `<script>$(function() { /* on page load */ $(".button_1 input").on("click",function() { /* on click of the checkbox */ $.get(this.checked? "/at_green_position_button/" :  "/at_red_position_button/", function(data) { console.log(data) }); });</script>` after the first script tag

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks a lot for your help. But I can't do that. Can you share any [codepen](https://codepen.io/)  link or in other online cite. My project was emergency, plzz help.

Comment: What does "I can't do that" mean?

Comment: Sorry for my language. I can't realize where <script>.... </script> should be placed. So that is my problem.

Comment: Between the `<head></head>` tags in your HTML document

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j3ecnbur/